# php active navbar with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do i make my navbar active with php?

```
<?php require_once 'backend/config.php'; ?>

<header>
    <ul>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header-navigatie">
                <li><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/??/??.php">Catogorie 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/resourcesTasks/index.php">Kaban</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/resourcesTasks/create.php">Nieuwe task</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn active" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/index.php">Home</a></li>
                <a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/index.php"><img class="logo_nav" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/img/logo-big-v4.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>        
</header>
<script>
    var header = document.getElementById("header-navigatie");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

            if (current.length > 0) {
                 current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            this.className += " active";
        });
    } 
</script>
```

how do i make this an active navbar. in my other pages i am using require_once to get this header, but everytime i switch the active navbar resets.

Comment: you can check the current url if it is match with menu url you can set class active

Comment: It's because you're changing the class name only on click. when the page navigates, all js code is re-run and everything is reset. You need to do this with PHP by comparing current URL with each `a` tags' `href`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your JS and for each menu item check (with PHP) if current page path is equal to that one. Something like:

```
<li><a class="btn<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category3') echo ' active'; ?>" href="/category3">Category 3</a></li>
<li><a class="btn<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/resourcesTasks/index.php') echo ' active'; ?>" href="/resourcesTasks/index.php">Kaban</a></li>
...
```

Didn't test it, but you get the point.